# How can I pass the Web Content Form data to a PlaceHolder in a UserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, master-pages

first time here on StackOverflow and it's a pleasure to be here, hope to have a nice time with all off you and to help with anything I can.

Well the question I'm asking is just what I have put in the title, the thing is I'm using a Master Page with four User Controls to fill the Master Page witch works fine,but in one of the User Controls (Principal.ascx) I have put a PlaceHolder with witch I wish to change the data in it depending on the page that is being loaded, per example if I wish to load the Register Employee page, I would send that to the placeholder and show it or if I wish to load the login page I would send that to the place holder and show it. So the code I'm handling is:

MasterPage:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/Head.ascx" TagName="Head" TagPrefix="hdr" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/Foot.ascx" TagName="Foot" TagPrefix="ftr" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/Menu.ascx" TagName="Menu" Tagprefix="mnu" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/Principal.ascx" TagName="Principal" Tagprefix="prn" %>

<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Css/Styles.css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </head>
<body>
   <form runat="server" id="MainForm">
      <div class="Container">
        <hdr:Head runat="server" ID="hdrHead" />
        <mnu:Menu runat="server" ID="menMenu" />
        <prn:Principal runat="server" ID="priPincipal" />
        <ftr:Foot runat="server" ID="ftrFoot" />
      </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no code behind on the master page yet.

And on the Menu UserControl is a simple menu managed using JQuery UI, after I'm able to make the login page work with the UserControl I will try to make this menu dynamic and only show menu levels that are relevant to the user that access the page:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Css/jquery-ui-1.10.0.css" />
<script src="../Js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#menu").menu();
});            
</script>

<div class="MenuContainer">
   <span style="margin: 20px 10px; padding: 5px;">
       Bienvenido, Usuario.
   </span>
<div class="Menu">
    <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Base de Conocimientos</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Vista general</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Agregar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Documentaci&oacute;n HGI</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Documentos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Agregar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Beneficios</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Medio d&iacute;a libre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vacaciones</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Mantenimiento</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">C&oacute;digos</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Vista General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Agregar</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>  
        <li><a href="#">Configuraciones</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Vista General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Agregar</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>    
        </ul>   
    </li>                            
    <li><a href="#">Salir</a></li>   
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the UserControl where I want to load the content is calles Principal.ascx:

```
<div class="Contenido">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder">

    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

I wish to display in the place holder a test text has fallows from the page default.aspx:

```
<span>
    This is the test.
<span/>
```

none of the UserControls or the MasterPage have any type of code on there .cs pages.